# Binary classification with seperate training and testing datasets

Tags: linear-regression, xgboost, binary-classification

I have two datasets (train.csv) and (test.csv) revolving around predicting the death outcome for a disease. Both sets include 20 independent variables (age, weight, etc), but only the train.csv dataset contains the true death outcome (0 for alive, 1 for death). The training dataset has a shape of (650, 21), whereas the test dataset has a shape of (200, 20). I'm also using python, and the dataset is imbalanced with only around 30 deaths in the training set.

I have to train the model using the training set, and predict the outcome using the test dataset, as well as display stuff such as performance tables. I then have to put the predicted outcomes into a new .csv file for submission which gets tested against a different dataset and gives me an ROC/AUC score. This submission has to have the same amount of observations as the test dataset, which is 200.

I just have a few questions revolving around this.

1. Do I have to use train_test_split on the training dataset? Or is it uneccsary because I already have seperate training/testing datasets?
2. I've created 2 different models using XGBoost and a Linear regression model. However, the accuracy for the training model tends to be really high (0.8-0.98), but when submitting my predictions to test on kaggle, it has a really low AUC/ROC score (0.5 or lower). Is this due to overfitting or is there another issue?
3. Is there any way to get an accurate AUC/ROC score for my predictions before I submit them to kaggle? I only have a limited amount of submissions, and I would like to know I'm atleast submitting something good rather than wasting all my submissions. Sorry if that is worded confusingly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, here's what I think:

1. I would always recommend splitting the training set if the amount of data allows it. Your train/test split in the train data wil then be a train/validation split. The validation set will allow you to test your model for things such as overfitting on the training data.
   Even though you can get the ROC/AUC score for the test set predictions, you can't use this for tuning your model, as this would be data leakage.
2. This question is a big part of the whole data science process, and too broad to be answered in this context. Try your best to try different configurations and see what works best! :)
   Also, high train set performance and low test set performance can never be **due to** overfitting, it **is** overfitting.
3. Yes, see the train/validation split suggestion in part 1.

Comment: Validation set! Everything makes more sense now, thank you.